# How to debug upgrade of ruby-on-rails mac osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Need help debugging upgrade to Ruby and Rails gems in order to launch webservice, and push to Heroku.

I have tried upgrading the Ruby version and Rails to have my webservice launch my application again on my MAC v 10.14.4 to meet Heroku requirements:

> "The default Ruby for new apps will be one minor version behind the most 
>   recent one. For instance, when Ruby 2.6.0 comes out, Ruby 2.5.x will become > the default."

I keep getting this error:

> [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Illformed requirement ["ruby 
>   2.5.0"]. Bundler cannot continue.
>
> #  from /Users/waf-mbp/Documents/Ruby/RoR/2100_Solution_blogs/Gemfile:2
>    #  -------------------------------------------
>    #  source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> > ruby "ruby 2.5.0"

I need help resolving this error regardless of the version showing in Gemfile.  I need to push my updates to Heroku.

I am using pg to power the web-service.

after running "rails s" I get this error:
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    railties (= 5.2.0)

In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)

```
jquery-rails was resolved to 4.3.3, which depends on
  railties (>= 4.2.0)

rails (= 5.2.0) was resolved to 5.2.0, which depends on
  railties (= 5.2.0)

sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
```

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "ruby 2.5.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.2.3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'puma'

gem 'rake'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small syntax error in the `Gemfile`: the line for the ruby interpreter should simply be

`ruby "2.5.0"`